# Add TextView on top of a LinearLayout Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/rect"
            android:id="@+id/searchRelativeLayout">
        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayoutProc"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp">
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/inputQuery"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
                    style="@style/AutoCompleteTextViewOrangeAutoComplete"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm trying to add, without success, a `TextView` dynamically on top off that `LinearLayout`, this is, in the end, the `LinearLayout` should be below the added `TextView`

This is my code:

```
        RelativeLayout compareLayout = (RelativeLayout) layoutToShow.findViewById(R.id.searchRelativeLayout);
        TextView compareItemOneMessage = new TextView(mContext);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        compareItemOneMessage.setLayoutParams(lp);
        compareItemOneMessage.setTextAppearance(mContext, android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large);
        compareItemOneMessage.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        compareItemOneMessage.setTypeface(fontBold);
        compareItemOneMessage.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.orange));
        compareItemOneMessage.setText("test");
        compareLayout.addView(compareItemOneMessage);
```

The new `TextView` is added but it's overlapped with the content of the `EditText`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a rule to keep it at top

```
compareItemOneMessage.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
```

and you also need to add rule for linearlayout to put it down.

```
LinearLayout l =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutProc);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = l.getLayoutParams();
l.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, your_text_view_id);
```

Comment: Because LinearLayout should be labeled RelativeLayout.  ALso you need layout.addView(view,params);

Comment: @easycheese no it shouldn't be RelativeLayout if you meant above solution. We're adding a rule to linearlayout inside a relativelayout and no need to add the linearlayout view again since it's already added. That's why I used "getLayoutParams()" in there.

Answer (score 0):

I would do somthing like that:

```
// Create the textView here


compareLayout.addView(compareItemOneMessage);
List<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
views.add(compareItemOneMessage);
for(int i=0; i<compareLayout.getChildCount(); ++i)
{
  views.add( compareLayout.getChildAt(i) );
  compareLayout.removeView( compareLayout.getChildAt(i) );
}

for (int i=0; i<views.size(); i++) compareLayout.addView(views.get(i));
```

This should do the job. I haven't tested it as I'm not on a dev desktop.

```
ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
LayoutParams layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();
parent.addViewInLayout(compareItemOneMessage, 0, layoutParams);
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting this `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first`

Comment: Just give me a second ;)

Comment: Thanks but what is `view`? and I'm getting error in `addViewInLayout`. It says it has protected access in android.view.ViewGroup

Comment: View is your parent view. Basically, give an Id to the main view and retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

i can't imagine how it looks and what kind of overlapping you get (maybe you should provide an image).
but why are you using `RelativeLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` as root? `LinearLayout` works better in the most cases.

you could try `padding` or `margin` to fix overlapping.

it also might be because of the `orientation` of the `Layout`

the problem with `IllegalStateException` can be fixed this way *(but pls only reuse stuff this way if you know the lifetime of your view what was the last parent)*:

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
vg.removeView(view);
//then do the stuff that adds the view - whatever failed before
linearLayout.add(view);
```